# Expected number of days it will take for two seeds to grow if each seed has a 50% chance to grow each day

Tags: probability, expected-value

I came across this video by Presh Talkwaker: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RY7YKSw1t_M.

I attempted to solve the problem by first figuring out the expected number of days for a single seed.

Per the definition of expected value, the number of days in which you would expect the seed to sprout would be $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nP(\text{seed not grown on day n})$. P(seed not grown on day n) = $\frac{1}{2^n}$ and after a lengthy calculation, I figured out that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}$ converges to 2 which seems to match the answer that Presh got.

However I'm running into issues figuring out the expected number of days which you would expect it to take for two seeds to grow. Let S(n) be the event where seed S remains ungrown on day n. Let the two seeds be named A and B.

I reasoned the expected value for two seeds would be $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nP(\text{A(n) or B(n)})$. Per the principle of inclusion exclusion, P(A(n) or B(n)) = P(A(n)) + P(B(n)) - P(A(n) and B(n)). Additionally, P(A(n)) = P(B(n)) (seed A has the same chance to remain not grown on day n as seed B does) and P(A(n) and B(n)) = P(A(n)) * P(B(n)) (they are independent events). Finally $P(A(n)) = \frac{1}{2^n}$. Simplifying, we get P(A(n) or B(n)) = $\frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^n} - (\frac{1}{2^n} \cdot \frac{1}{2^n}) = \frac{2}{2^n} - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} = \frac{4}{2^{n+1}} - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} = \frac{3}{2^{n+1}}$

Thus the expected value for two seeds would be $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{3n}{2^{n+1}}$

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{3n}{2^{n+1}} = 3/2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^{n}} = 3/2 \cdot 2 = 3$

However this answer is incorrect. Presh gets an answer of 8/3, and I understand his method. However I'm not sure where I am going wrong in my approach. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Excellent videos that Presh has, eh? He's got some videos that he's made out of answers here. So if anything, you're in the right place. +1, I'll see if I can address your issue.

Answer (score 1):

One issue I see with your calculation is that you seem to have $\frac{1}{2^n}\cdot \frac{1}{2^n}$ equal to $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$, but it should be equal to $\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$